# unexpected pandas broadcasting behavior

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

**edit:**
A simple mistake/bug caused some non-explainable problems. I edited the question to leave the part that actually can be explained and for which answers have been posted.

---

I am struggling to understand the following indexing behavior:
Suppose I have some `pd.DataFrame`:

```
In [18]: Df = pd.DataFrame(zip(list('abcde'),sp.randn(5)),index=range(5),columns=['label','val'])

In [19]: Df
Out[19]: 
  label       val
0     a -0.705392
1     b  0.087682
2     c  1.519180
3     d  1.363852
4     e -0.004182
```

And I am trying to normalize all values of `val` by one of them, say `c`.
Intuitively I would write

```
Df['val'] / Df.loc[Df['label'] == 'c']['val']
```

But the result this triggers some broadcasting behavior I do not fully understand:

```
In [20]: Df['val'] / Df.loc[Df['label'] == 'c']['val']
Out[20]: 
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: When I saw the title my first thought was to point you towards [https://biology.stackexchange.com/](https://biology.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dividing a `Series` by a `Series`, which is causing pandas to align on index. If you look at the value produced via indexing:

```
df.loc[df['label'] == 'c']['val']
2    1.51918
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

... you'll see this is a `Series`. If you further index this `Series`:

```
df.loc[df['label'] == 'c']['val'][2]
1.51918
```

... we're now left with:

```
type(df.loc[df['label'] == 'c']['val'][2])
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

And if we attempt dividing the whole `val` Series by this:

```
df.val / df.loc[df['label'] == 'c']['val'][2]
0   -0.464324
1    0.057717
2    1.000000
3    0.897755
4   -0.002753
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

... we have the expected behavior.

Please note, this kind of messy chained indexing is NOT how you should be dividing a whole `Series` by a singular value...

Comment: Can you recommend the best way on how to divide a `Series` by a singular value derived from another place in a `DataFrame`/`Series`?

Comment: @grgrsr I think it really varies depending on the data set. For example, what if there are two records with label == 'c'? This approach would not be ideal

Comment: In this specific example, I was sure that `label == c` is unique, but I agree that this is quite specific. However, I still can't see another way of getting the float then via messy chain indexing or casting.

Comment: @grgrsr I think generally speaking pulling an arbitrary value from a column to work with would not be considered best practices. Is there anything that would remain constant through time to allow you to find this value (5 observations prior, first observation, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

[I think what happens here is that you are not allowed to divide Series by other Series directly - via the `/` operator. There is a `pandas.Series.divide` function for that.] **EDIT**: apparently you can and I am dumb.

If you convert `Df.loc[Df['label'] == 'c']['val']` to a float you will have no problem dividing a Series object by it:

```
foo = float(Df.loc[Df['label'] == 'c']['val'])
Df['val'] / foo
```

Comment: So in my code where I this problem appeared I did exactly this - get the float and then I continued. But then I got a bit curious why this happens, especially the reason why the second line is the only one left non-`NaN`, even though the index of the `Series` object is `0`

Comment: You are right - It is completely incorrect as I can not reproduce the `0`. I must have edited the Data mistakenly in between copying it into the Stackoverflow window. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: my bad then - I was not able to do it. Edited appropriately.

However: I tried the code in one of my own pandas dataframes and also had the column of NaNs and the lone normal value in the middle. Don't know how broadcasting works for Series.

Comment: if the `.loc` derived slice has an index of `2`, then it makes sense in the context of alignment, as this division is the only that is permitted. in my initial post, the index was `0`.